# groovy split string by pipe and return substring index

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to split the header row of a pipe delimited text data file and return the index of two fields that could be in any position as the structure of our data varies from campaign to campaign.  An example of my code is:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList()
def headingslist = "URN|BATCHID|CUST_URN|CUSTOMER_NAME|POSTCODE|PERSONKEY|MOBILENUMBER||PREMIUM|STATUS"
headingslist.split("\\|")

list.add(headingslist)

int indexMobNo = list.indexOf("MOBILENUMBER")
int indexURN = list.indexOf("PERSONKEY")
```

However, when I run this code or variations of it, I get the index returned as -1 as it can't find either substring in my string.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `split` will not modify the value of `headingslist` but return a List. So you can either assign the result to `list` directly or use `list.addAll` to add all elements of the result to the list. Note that `add` would add the `List` itself as a new element to the List. So you would end up with a List that contains one element that is a List.

```
def headingslist = "URN|BATCHID|CUST_URN|CUSTOMER_NAME|POSTCODE|PERSONKEY|MOBILENUMBER||PREMIUM|STATUS"
ArrayList list = headingslist.split("\\|")

int indexMobNo = list.indexOf("MOBILENUMBER")
int indexURN = list.indexOf("PERSONKEY")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that's perfect

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as answered so other know that they don't need to look into it.